# IllegalStateException when deploying spring mvc application on weblogic server

Tags: java, spring-mvc, remote-server, weblogic12c, illegalstateexception

I developed a spring mvc application in my local machine successfully. I used java 1.8.0_51 , spring 4.3.4 and weblogic 12.2.1.0.0 .   Now I want to deploy this application into remote server .  That server  consists weblogic 12.1.3.0.0 and java 1.8.0_20 . But when I deploying the application into that server deployment fails with below exception .

**java.lang.IllegalStateException: Context namespace element 'component-scan' and its parser class [org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser] are only available on JDK 1.5 and higher**

Highly appreciate your help for fixing this issue.

Comment: are you sure weblogic has java 1.8? error message suggests jdk is really old there

Comment: yes , I double checked it.

Comment: I could fix the issue by adding below code segment into weblogic.xml file.                                                                                              <container-descriptor>
        <servlet-reload-check-secs>-1</servlet-reload-check-secs>
        <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
    </container-descriptor>                                                                                               Above code segment  says don't get libraries from the weblogic server. Refer libraries which are already included in the project.